# Got double "onmouseover" Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

first can you look on those two image so you understand.

***When not hover:*** http://s15.postimg.org/sn6rk45rf/not_Hover.png
**When hover:** http://s16.postimg.org/yk6beg1ad/on_Hover.png

Right now when I have my mouse over a image, both image get buttons.
But I just want each image have theve own buttons on mouse over and the other image hide the buttons.

I don't really know how to fix it, and I'm very beginner with Javascript.

Here is my HTML/CSS/Javascript codes.

```js
var buttonNew = document.getElementsByClassName('buttonNewest');
var buttonRan = document.getElementsByClassName('buttonRandom');
function imageOver() {
    for(var i = 0; i < buttonNew.length; i++) {
      buttonNew[i].style.display = "block";
      buttonNew[i].style.animation = "moveButtonsRight 2s";
    }
    for(var i = 0; i < buttonRan.length; i++) {
      buttonRan[i].style.display = "block";
      buttonRan[i].style.animation = "moveButtonsLeft 2s";
    }
}

function imageLeave() {
  for(var i = 0; i < buttonNew.length; i++) {
      buttonNew[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    for(var i = 0; i < buttonRan.length; i++) {
        buttonRan[i].style.display = "none";
      }
  }
```

```css
.charSelect[role="Background"] {
  width: 1600px;
  min-height: 600px;
  margin: 25px auto;
}

.charSelect[role="Background"] > h1 {
  width: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: dashed 2px  rgba(255, 207, 0, 0.75);
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 2.6em;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 3px rgb(0, 0, 0);
}

.charSelect[role="Characters"] {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 250px;
  height: auto;
  background: rgba(42, 42, 42, 0.7);
  border: dashed 2px  rgba(255, 207, 0, 0.4);
  color: rgba(255, 207, 0, 1);
  opacity: 0.6;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 1s;
  margin-left: 250px;

}
.charSelect[role="Characters"]:hover {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: scale(1.05);
}

.charSelect[role="Names"] {
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 1.8em;
}

.charSelect[role="Names"] > p {
  margin: 0 !important;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px rgb(0, 0, 0);
}

/* Buttons */
.charSelect[role="LatestVid"], .charSelect[role="RandomVid"] {
  width: 170px;
  height: 45px;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgb(255, 207, 0), rgba(255, 207, 0, 0));
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 45px;
  color: black;
  -webkit-transition: background 1s;
  transition: background 1s;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px;
}
.charSelect[role="LatestVid"] {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top:50%;
  right: 70%;
}

.charSelect[role="RandomVid"] {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top:50%;
  left: 70%;
}
.charSelect[role="RandomVid"]:hover , .charSelect[role="LatestVid"]:hover {
  background: rgb(255, 207, 0);
}


/* Animation */

@-webkit-keyframes moveButtonsLeft {
  0% {
    left: 50%;
  }
  100% {
    left: 70%;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes moveButtonsRight {
  0% {
    right: 50%;
  }
  100% {
    right: 70%;
  }
}
```

```html
<!-- Character one -->
    <div onmouseover="imageOver()" onmouseleave="imageLeave()" class="charSelect" role="Characters">
      <img src="chars/Dekker.gif" width="250"/>
      <a href="#"> <div class="charSelect buttonNewest" role="LatestVid">Newest Videos</div> </a>
    <a href="#"> <div  class="charSelect buttonRandom" role="RandomVid">Random Videos</div> </a>
      <div class="charSelect" role="Names"><p>Dekker</p></div>
  </div>



  <!-- Character two -->
  <div onmouseover="imageOver()" onmouseleave="imageLeave()" class="charSelect" role="Characters">
    <img src="chars/Dekker.gif" width="250"/>
    <a href="#"> <div class="charSelect buttonNewest" role="LatestVid">Newest Videos</div> </a>
  <a href="#"> <div  class="charSelect buttonRandom" role="RandomVid">Random Videos</div> </a>
    <div class="charSelect" role="Names"><p>Dekker</p></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't know why you use JS... If I'm reading your question well, this can be all done with CSS alone.

Comment: Try to learn libraries such as knockout js or angularjs for this kind of functionalities, because in the future, they are gonna be useful.

Answer (score 2):

You're calling an `imageOver()` that loops **all** your elements.

Instead of using JS (at all) I'd go with pure CSS:

```css
*{font: 14px/1 sans-serif;}

.charSelect{
  position: relative;
  display:  inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.charButtons{
  position:  absolute;
  bottom:    40px;
  width:     100%;
  text-align:center;
  opacity:    0;
  visibility: hidden;
          transition: 0.4s;
  -webkit-transition: 0.4s;
}
.charButtons a{
  display:    block;
  margin-top: 1px;
  text-align: center;
  color:      #fff;
  background: #444;
  padding:    10px;
  opacity:    0.9;
          transition: 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition: 0.3s;
}
.charButtons a:hover{ opacity:1; }
.charSelect:hover .charButtons{
  visibility: visible;
  opacity:    1;
}
```

```html
<div class="charSelect">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/180x150/4af/&text=Hero+1">
  <div class="charButtons">
    <a href="#">Newest Videos</a>
    <a href="#">Random Videos</a>
  </div>
  <h2>HERO 1</h2>
</div>

<div class="charSelect">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/180x150/fa4/&text=Hero+2">
  <div class="charButtons">
    <a href="#">Newest Videos</a>
    <a href="#">Random Videos</a>
  </div>
  <h2>HERO 2</h2>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for a great answer!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're not reffering tot the current object that you have cursor on. If you go with with cursor over and image, your function will apply those changes for all `buttonNew` and `buttonRan` that can be found on page.

Comment: Thanks dpaul, I trying to learn Javascript so thanks for that answer!